# How to get server name (only without SQL Server instance) from connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I'd like to test if a SQL Server exists with tcp socket (it's faster if server doesn't exist).

If the connection string something like this:

```
name="DefaultConnection" 
connectionString="Data Source=COMPUTERNAME\SQLSERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
```

I'd like to use this method:

```
public bool CheckServerAvailablity(string sServerAddressOrName)
{
        try
        {
             string connectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectString);
            // Retrieve the DataSource property.    
            string sServerAddressOrName = builder.DataSource;
            int port = 1433;
            IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(sServerAddressOrName);
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostEntry.AddressList[0];

            TcpClient TcpClient = new TcpClient();
            TcpClient.Connect(ipAddress, port);
            TcpClient.Close();

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is: `sServerAddressOrName = COMPUTERNAME\SQLSERVERNAME`, but I need only `COMPUTERNAME`.

So, the question is how to get `COMPUTERNAME` only?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are assuming SQL Server is listening on 1433 port. But 1433 is the default port for the default instance. Named instances uses dynamic ports by default. Additionally, default instance can be configured to listen on another port. Therefore, CheckServerAvailablity won't work even for default instances. Getting the computer name from connection string is a trivial problem, you can solve it with String.Split(). But getting the port SQL Server listen on is not, you need to talk to SQL Server Browser service

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're absolutely right, but the environment this question belongs to, use TCP/IP connections only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [`DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) property of [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) gets the name/network address of the instance of SQL Server to connect to.

In your case, it's the hostname of the machine and SQL Server instance name, delimited with `\`.

If you just need something that works in this specific scenario, you can just access the `DataSource` and split the string on the `\` character, like so:

```
String myConnectionString = "Data Source=COMPUTERNAME\\SQLSERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(myConnectionString);
String hostname = builder.DataSource.Split(new Char[] { '\\' })[0]);
```

That said, the above approach isn't exactly versatile, and won't work for more complex values of `DataSource`.

[Since you can't use `\` in a SQL Server instance name](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143744(v=sql.90).aspx), we can leverage this information to produce a *slightly* better solution:

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
Int32 length = builder.DataSource.LastIndexOf('\\');
Int32 start = builder.DataSource.LastIndexOf('\\', length - 1) + 1;
if (start == length) { start = 0; } else { length -= start; }
var hostname = builder.DataSource.Substring(start, length);
```

I should add, however, that even *this* solution won't work if the data source is specified using named pipes (`\\COMPUTERNAME\pipe\pipeName`), port numbers (`COMPUTERNAME:1433`) or the force TCP parameter (i.e. `tcp:COMPUTERNAME`).

Comment: The OP already uses SqlConnectionStringBuilder, why the need to link to it?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I Suppose I overlooked it.  At any rate, I'll leave it because it doesn't detract from the rest of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but this answer can be used in this special case only. If the instance name is more complex, than it won't work.

Comment: @Joshua, Thanks! This is what I did also.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Split()` function for that like

```
string sServerAddressOrName = builder.DataSource.Split('\\')[0];
```

Comment: Watched your answer quickly go from `/` to ` \\ ` to ` \\ `.  I knew you'd get there eventually. ;)  Edit: Hah, and now it's happening to me in my comment!

Comment: Yes, didn't recognize the exact character but that's not the point though. Whole idea is to use `Split()` function.

Comment: Thanks, but what if the instance name is something like this: \\COMPUTERNAME\\SQLSERVER?

Comment: @Rahul, your answer solves the problem of getting the computer name, but it doesn't solve the problem of checking server availability. Named SQL Server instances don't listen on 1433 port by default

Comment: @NotanywhoNotanywho, in that case you will have to change your Split() method to get element at 1.

Comment: @JesúsLópez, I feel you haven't red the post carefully cause the question was *how to get computername from con string*. What you said is correct but that's not a question here and so didn't felt to address.

Comment: @Rahul, yes, but i can't do it in runtime. :) However your answer helped me with a little workaround.